# How to get data from NSArray in block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

everytime i will call a block, my NSArray is clear. Is there a solution how to get data from block??

```
- (void)reload {
    products = nil;
    products= [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *storeProducts) {
        if (success) {
            products = storeProducts;//i need products (NSArray)
        }
    }];}
```

It is calling SKProductRequest then. And as i know it is a callback. Thank for your help :)

Comment: you need to declare it as block variable

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with asynchronous fetching of data and you have yet to learn what that means.

Comment: so in this case, isnt there a need to declare the array as block var @trojanfoe

Comment: Not for instance variables, no.  I might be wrong with my comment, however it's not clear what is being asked.

Comment: should it be a global var or block var?

Comment: Do the things you need to do right after the line  `products = storeProducts;` in the `success` scope. If `products` is a instance variable it's supposed to be `self.products = storeProducts;`

Comment: @petulo72 It should be neither; it should be an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying the `products` var from within the block you need to declare it as a `__block` so the variable will live in shared storage.  If you don't declare it as a `__block` the var value is all that is passed to the block and it cannot be modified.  As per the Docs:

> Use __block Variables to Share Storage
>
> If you need to be able to change the value of a captured variable from
>   within a block, you can use the __block storage type modifier on the
>   original variable declaration. This means that the variable lives in
>   storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the original
>   variable and any blocks declared within that scope.

[See details here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK to me, in that `products` (an instance variable, I assume) will get assigned when the *request* is complete and the completion handler is called.

(On a minor note, there is no need to do `products= [[NSArray alloc] init];` if `products` is going to be re-assigned).

I assume your issue is that `products` remains empty after calling this method, and that's because the call is *asynchronous* (i.e. runs in a separate thread of execution from the one that calls it).  This is the reason for the completion handler pattern; to store the received data and notify the rest of your code.

Therefore forget about looking at `products` until you are told it's ready by doing additional work within the completion handler block:

```
- (void)reload {
    products = nil;
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *storeProducts) {
        if (success) {
            products = storeProducts;

            // UPDATE UI - MUST BE DONE IN MAIN THREAD
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reload];    // Reload the tableview
            });

            // CALL A PRIVATE METHOD
            [self heyProductsHasUpdated];

        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)reload 
{
    __block typeof(self) safeSelf = self;

    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *storeProducts) 
    {
       if (success) 
       {
          [safeSelf setProducts:[NSArray arrayWithArray:storeProducts]];

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [safeSelf.tableView reload];
          });
       }
    }];
}
```

Comment: OK, so if `products` is a local variable, how can it be accessed from the tableview?

Answer (score -1):

declare products like so:

```
__block NSArray *products = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: `__block` is not required for instance variables (I am assuming that `products` is an instance variable).

Comment: u are right @trojanfoe